# Emacs window (frame) disappeared

Tags: emacs, gdb

I am running emacs under gdb on linux.

I ran ediff, hit q in the tiny "command" frame and *both* it *and* the main emacs frame disappeared.  I.e., there are no emacs frames (windows) on my desktop. However, emacs is still running (at 100% CPU!):

```
13425 sds       20   0  639m 179m  12m R  99.7  2.3  30:48.11 emacs
```

Gdb mentions `_XError` and `delete_frame` in `bt` (`xbacktrace` does not work: `No symbol "backtrace_function" in current context.`), so I guess, emacs is dead.

Is there a way to tell gdb to tell Emacs to save buffers?

Comment: While it would be pretty awesome to do this through gdb, can you just send SIGHUP to the emacs process and use `recover-this-file` after you restart emacs?

Comment: @assem: this recovers from auto-save which is not necessarily up to date